# Как построить scatterplot, если прозрачность каждой точки дана в столбце 'values'?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, scatter

```
for i in train.index:
    sns.scatterplot(x = train['x'][i], y = train['y'][i], alpha = train['values'][i])
```

Данный код выводит ошибку:

```
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Следующий код:

```
sns.scatterplot(x = train['x'], y = train['y'], alpha = train['values'])
```

Выводит следующую ошибку:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужна именно прозрачность? Когда точки будут накладываться ситуация будет не очень понятной. Обычно используют либо размер, либо палитру цветов. В принципе, вы можете сделать свою палитру и в ней сделать различные значения `alpha` у цветов. Так получится, но смысл непонятен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то мне кажется, что в seaborne нет возможности варьировать прозрачность внутри одного графика. Впрочем, как и в matplotlib. Зато в последнем можно сделать вот так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
train=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5],
                 'y':[10,11,12,13,14],
                 'values':[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9]})
for i in train.index:
    plt.scatter(x = train['x'][i], y = train['y'][i], c = 'red', alpha = train['values'][i])
```

Получаем:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможность есть, но только через создание своей палитры, где у каждого цвета будет разная `alpha`, насколько я понял. И палитру опять же придётся через `matplotlib` делать. Ну то есть простой возможности нет )

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, Вы скорее всего правы. У меня как-то с seaborn не сложилось. А может - просто пока matplotlib на все мои хотелки хватает.

Comment: спасибо, помогло!